# What are the differences between these compound adjectives? Shoe in the shape of slipper/ Shoe shaped like slipper/ Slipper-shaped shoe

Tags: sentence-construction

I wanted to know the difference between these three phrases ( **Shoe in the shape of slipper/ Shoe shaped like slipper/ Slipper-shaped shoe**  ) and why the third one is the right answer in the following sentence.

> In cold climates, an entirely different type of shoe was used - the moccasin - **a slipper-shaped** shoe made of soft but sturdy leather.

Comment: The first two are ungrammatical, but I don't think that's quite what you're actually asking.

Comment: shaped like a slipper = slipper-shaped shoe.

Comment: What was the question? What were the alternatives you were given? What did your teacher say? There's no real difference between a "slipper-shaped shoe" and a "shoe shaped like a slipper" and a "shoe in the shape of a slipper" but you don't seem to understand how to use the indefinite article "a".

Comment: **Shoe in the shape of slipper** and  **Shoe shaped like slipper** are both incorrect.  The indefinite article is missing before slipper in both these examples.

Answer (score 0):

The first two sound like a shoe that has been purposely designed to resemble a slipper.

The last one sounds like a shoe that happens to be shaped like a slipper.

In this context, the this last one is a better choice since the moccasin was not designed to be similar to the slipper. It's a coincidence that the two look similar.

Comment: What is the difference between a slipper and  a shoe designed to look like one, considering that a slipper is already a kind of shoe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In everyday life, I distinguish between slippers and shoes. A slipper is technically a shoe, but I can't imagine anyone referring to a slipper as a shoe.

Comment: I'd say that a slipper is a comfortable slip-on shoe that is worn indoors, and I'd see little difference between a hat designed to look like a beret, and a beret.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a case of possible misplaced modifier problem, for the first two phases, than one of shoe shape description accuracy comparison.

...**a shoe in the shape of [a] slipper** made of soft but sturdy leather

...**a shoe shaped like [a] slipper** made of soft but sturdy leather

...**a slipper-shaped shoe** made of soft but sturdy leather

The adjectival phrase *made of soft but sturdy leather* is meant to modify **shoe**; hence, placing **shoe** just before the phrase seems better.

Edit

To use the first two options, adding a comma after *slipper* could make it clearer that *made of soft but sturdy leather* modifies *shoe*.

> In cold climates, an entirely different type of shoe was used, the moccasin, **a shoe shaped like a slipper**, made of soft but sturdy leather.

I prefer to use commas than em dashes.

Comment: In your first two examples you need "**a** slipper". You may need to follow "slipper" with "**and**" or a comma (depending on the rest of the sentence) as well.

Comment: Thx, @Peter.  I have edited my answer.